# Button command attribute not working as expected in Tkinter?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

When I try to create a button with an event listener in Tkinter, it shows the following error:

```py
button = Button(main_window, text="Sumbit" command = click()).grid(row=3, column=1)
                                                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Here's the code of the event listener:

```py
def click():
    print("The entered name is {edit_txt1} and the entered age is {edit_txt2}.")
```

Can anyone help me resolve the issue, the error message itself does not help at all?

> I am using Python 3.6.9 on Zorin OS Lite 15 along with Tk version 2.6. (if it helps)

Comment: You have a syntax error, not a TkInter problem.  You need to put a comma after text='submit'.

Comment: @PaulCornelius my bad, or worse. Thanks for objecting.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You're missing a `,`

```py
button = Button(main_window, text="Sumbit", command=click).grid(row=3, column=1)
```

Comment: Another problem, this will trigger the function even before the button is clicked.

Comment: While it's true that the code is missing a comma, your solution is not correct because it calls `click()` immediately rather than waiting for the button to be clicked.